# How can I check if a MFC CString is null?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, c-strings

I want to check if a MFC CString is null or not. Is there a way to do this?

PS: I want to check if it is null not if it's empty.

CString m_strName;

[image]

Comment: MFC CString cannot be null

Comment: A _pointer_ can be null but an _object_ cannot be null. If you have a pointer just write `if (mypointer == NULL) ...`, but that is rather obvious.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Ben if the internal ptr is null the CString is empty.

Comment: We don't know what *tokres* is. We also don't know, what sort of visualizers you have installed. As posted, the question doesn't contain enough information to answer it.

Comment: I am trying to copy the tokres.m_strName which is CString into m_strName which is also a CString. This calls the overloading of the operator= of CString (CSimpleStringT& operator=(_In_ const CSimpleStringT& strSrc)) and crashes because it cannot get the value of the string. This is why i want to check if tokres.m_strName is NULL

Comment: tokres is an object of a class containing CString m_strName; data member.

Comment: It seems that your `tokres` is not properly initialized. That's why all class members are pretty much garbage. You should post entire code. So we can help you out.

Comment: Are you sure that `tokres.m_strName` is a `CString` object, and not a pointer to a `CString` object (i.e. a `CString*`)? The *Watch* window seems to imply, that it is a pointer.

Comment: @IInspectable yes, it may even be a simple pointer to char.

Comment: @Mihai what exactly is `tokres`?

Comment: Since you didn't respond to any of the inquiries to clarify your question, I'm afraid I have to vote to close it off as unclear.

Comment: I have already written that tokres is an object of a class containing CString m_strName; data member. From how it looks like it might be a problem of initialization. Is there a way to check if the string is initialized.

Comment: Don't tell us what you **think** `tokres` is. Post the **real** code. Everything else is just asking us to guess, and my guess is, that you are doing it wrong. A `CString` class member will always be initialized, regardless of how the object is constructed. A `CString*` as a class member may or may not be initialized. You also need to answer what debug visualizers you have installed.

Answer (score 11):

A `CString` object is never `NULL`. Unlike a `char*` or `wchar*`, which can be `NULL`, the internal buffer of a `CString` object which is a pointer always points to a data. For a given `CString` object, you can only differentiate whether it is empty or not using `CString::IsEmpty()`.

For the same reason, the `LPCTSTR` cast operator never returns `NULL`.

Comment: ok, but in visual studio in debug the value of the cstring is null. I cannot check it with IsEmpty (it crashes because it cannot retrieve the length).

Comment: show your code snippet. it is only possible if your object has been destroyed or it is not initialized.

Comment: I added a picture. It has not been initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the internal layout of the `CString` class template<sup>1)</sup>, the pointer stored cannot ever be `NULL`.

The `CString` class template has a single class member: `m_pszData`. This member not only contains the string data, but also additional information (like string  length, reference count, buffer capacity, etc.; see [CStringData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/494hzt3b.aspx)). This additional information is stored to the left of the stored pointer. Both parts (string data and character buffer) must be allocated in a single block of memory, as there is only one pointer to reference both. Since the string data always needs to be there, the `m_pszData` can never be `NULL`.

---

<sup>1)</sup> `CString` is a typedef for a particular `CStringT` template instantiation. The `CStringT` itself is derived from the `CSimpleStringT` class template.